# Form action does not work for Android or iOS

Tags: html, forms, mobile

I am working on a prototype website.  It has a simple login form shown below.  It works fine on laptops.  It does not work in iOS (v11.2.6 with Chrome and Safari) or on my Chromebook (v69.0.3497.95).

```
<div class="form-popup" id="loginForm" align="center" >
    <form action="Login.php" method="post" class="form-container">
        <h1>Login</h1>

        <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Login">
        <input type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeLoginForm()" value="Close">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use bootstrap forms.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FORM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="loginForm">
            <form class="form-popup">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pws">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pws">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="login">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cancel" id="formButton">Close!</button>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#formButton").click(function() {
            $("#loginForm").toggle();
        });

    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do you connect this to the post to Login.php?

Comment: OK, I dug in a little further.  Login.php verifies the credentials and writes a cookie to give access.  The problem with the mobile platforms is that the cookie is not getting written.  Because this is a different problem that the topic for this question, I will close this as resolved.